# Keyframe Help With Arrow Keys

Tags: animation

Brand new to Blender, working through some tutorials and I'm currently doing some keyframe animation.  When I go to use the Arrow Keys to jump to frames, my left and right (-1/+1) keys are working correctly.  So is my down arrow key (-10).  However, anytime I try to jump ahead +10 frames with the up arrow key I get a message "No more keyframes to jump to in this direction".

This is happening even when I'm on the first frame, does anyone know how I can get my +10 frame jump key to work or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This would indicate old tutorials, historically up and down arrows used to jump 10 frames, now they jump between keyframes. It was somewhere in the 2.5x days that this was changed (couple of years ago). If you don't like the current key setup described by @CoDEmanX you can adjust them in preferences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>▲</kbd> jumps to next keyframe of the active object,
<kbd>▼</kbd> jumps to previous.

They don't change frame by +/- 10. If you wanna do so, use:

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>▲</kbd> +10 frames,
<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>▼</kbd> -10 frames.

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>◀</kbd> to jump to start frame,
<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>▶</kbd> for end frame.